# Trello API: Issue with corrupted content error authenticating a firefox extension with Trello

Tags: firefox, trello

I am using the trello_client.js > trello.authorize function to authorize a chrome extension with the trello api and everything is working successfully there.  I am now trying to port the extension to firefox using the webextensions approach.  The same code on firefox gives me a "Corrupted Content Error".  It looks like this may have something to do with the redirect location in Trello's response headers but I am struggling to find a solution.  Below is my response header (the token parameter in the location was modified to avoid sharing the actual token response).  Anyone else experience this and find a solution?

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
Content-Length: 330
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2016 23:50:37 GMT
Location: moz-extension://d5b5e7f9-a0d0-44ff-8d72-81d6455c6fbf/settings/index.html#token=ABCD
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Accept, Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
x-frame-options: DENY
x-trello-environment: Production
x-trello-version: 1.725.0

Comment: I am not sure if I encounter similar issue. But my firefox browser was not going to board page when signed in and in some case showing only top blue ribbon. But after clearing cache and cookies I was able to see and use full trello in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with the Pocket API and after asking in Mozilla's IRC channel discovered it's a bug in Firefox's Web Extensions, [see the bug report here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1276048).

Until that's patched you'd have to use a proxy or if it's just for your own use I've found clicking "try again" will push through the request and the redirect back to the extension then goes through successfully but not an ideal workflow and not sure if the same might be true for Trello.